# How to remove red margins in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I installed the "prettier" extension in VS code.
With indent settings of 2 spaces.

```
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
```

Now VS code highlights the indentation fields in red.
VS code wants there to be 4 spaces.
How can I set 2 spaces in VS code?
Or how can I remove this red highlight in VS code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem!
This is my **settings.json**

```
// Distance of padding.
"prettier.tabWidth": 2,
// The number of spaces corresponding to a tab.
"editor.tabSize": 2,
// Insert spaces when pressing the TAB key. This setting is overridden based on the content of the file if the "editor.detectIndentation" setting is enabled.
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
// Based on the contents of the file, determines whether "editor.tabSize" and "editor.insertSpaces" are automatically detected when the file is opened.
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
```